# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required argument "data" is missing and does not have an android:defaultValue

Tags: android

I try to pass data from API on recycleView on Home Activity to new activity and fragment, but I have a problem like this

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required argument "data" is missing and does not have an android:defaultValue
        at com.project.icacraft.ui.detail.DetailFragmentArgs$Companion.fromBundle(DetailFragmentArgs.kt:60)
        at com.project.icacraft.ui.detail.DetailFragment.onActivityCreated(DetailFragment.kt:35)
```

I have 2 recycleView, horizontal and vertical, here is my code for HomeAdapter:

```
    class HomeAdapter (
    private val listData: List<Data>,
    private val itemAdapterCallback: ItemAdapterCallback
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_horizontal, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(listData[position], itemAdapterCallback)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listData.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(data: Data, itemAdapterCallback: ItemAdapterCallback) {
            itemView.apply {
                tvTitle.text = data.name
                rbcraft.rating = data.rate?.toFloat()?:0f
                Glide.with(context)
                    .load(data.picturePath)
                    .into(ivPoster)
                itemView.setOnClickListener { view -> itemAdapterCallback.onClick(view, data) }
            }
        }
    }

    interface ItemAdapterCallback {
        fun onClick(v: View?, data: Data)
    }
}
```

HomePresenter:

```
class HomePresenter (private val view:HomeContract.View) : HomeContract.Presenter{

    private val mCompositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable?

    init {
        this.mCompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    }

    override fun getHome() {
        view.showLoading()
        val disposable = HttpClient.getInstance().getAPI()!!.home()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                {
                    view.dismissLoading()

                    if (it.meta?.status.equals("success")){
                        it.data?.let { data -> view.onHomeSuccess(data) }
                    } else {
                        view.onHomeFailed(it.meta?.message.toString())
                    }

                },
                {
                    view.dismissLoading()
                    view.onHomeFailed(it.getErrorBodyMessage())
                }
            )
        mCompositeDisposable!!.add(disposable)
    }

    override fun subscribe() {}

    override fun unSubscribe() {
        mCompositeDisposable!!.clear()
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Horizontal Recycleview on home:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), HomeAdapter.ItemAdapterCallback, HomeContract.View {

    private var adapter: HomeAdapter? = null
    var progressDialog: Dialog? = null
    private var newStateList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
    private var popularList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
    private var recomendedList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()

    private lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        initView()
        presenter = HomePresenter(this)
        presenter.getHome()

    }


    private fun initView() {
        progressDialog = Dialog(requireContext())
        val dialogLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loader, null)

        progressDialog?.let {
            it.setContentView(dialogLayout)
            it.setCancelable(false)
            it.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        }

        //menampilakn foto user
        var user = IcaCraft.getApp().getUser()
        var userResponse = Gson().fromJson(user, User::class.java)

        if (!userResponse.profile_photo_url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Glide.with(requireActivity())
                .load(userResponse.profile_photo_url)
                .into(ivProfile)
        }

    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?, data: Data) {
        var bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable("data", data)
        val detail = Intent(activity, DetailActivity::class.java).putExtras(bundle)
        startActivity(detail)
    }

    override fun onHomeSuccess(homeResponse: HomeResponse) {

        for (a in homeResponse.data.indices) {

            var items: List<String> = homeResponse.data[a].types?.split(",") ?: ArrayList()
            for (x in items.indices)
            {
                if (items[x].equals("new_craft", true)) {
                    newStateList?.add(homeResponse.data[a])
                } else if (items[x].equals("recommended", true)) {
                    recomendedList?.add(homeResponse.data[a])
                } else if (items[x].equals("popular", true)) {
                    popularList?.add(homeResponse.data[a])
                }
            }
        }

        adapter = HomeAdapter(homeResponse.data, this)
        val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        rvList.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rvList.adapter = adapter

        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(
            childFragmentManager
        )
        sectionsPagerAdapter.setData(newStateList, popularList, recomendedList)
//        viewPager!!.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }

    override fun onHomeFailed(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun showLoading() {
        progressDialog?.show()
    }

    override fun dismissLoading() {
        progressDialog?.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Code for SectionPagerAdapter

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(
        fm
    ) {


    var new_craft: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
    var popular: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
    var recommended: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        var fragment : Fragment
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                fragment = HomeNewCraftFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", new_craft)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                return fragment
            }
            1 -> {
                fragment = HomePopularFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", popular)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                return fragment
            }
            2 -> {
                fragment = HomeRecommendedFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", recommended)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                return fragment
            }
            else -> {
                fragment = HomeNewCraftFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", new_craft)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                return fragment
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "New Craft"
            1 -> "Popular"
            2 -> "Recommended"
            else -> null
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    fun setData(newStateListParms: ArrayList<Data>?, popularListParms: ArrayList<Data>?, recomendedListParms: ArrayList<Data>?) {
        new_craft = newStateListParms
        popular = popularListParms
        recommended = recomendedListParms
    }
}
```

Here is code for vertical recycleview adapter:

```
class HomeNewCraftAdapter (
    private val listData: ArrayList<Data>,
    private val itemAdapterCallback : ItemAdapterCallback
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeNewCraftAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_vertical, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(listData[position], itemAdapterCallback)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listData.size
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        fun bind(data : Data, itemAdapterCallback: ItemAdapterCallback){
            itemView.apply {
                tvTitle.text = data.name
                tvPrice.formatPrice(data?.price.toString())
                rbCraft.rating = data.rate?.toFloat() ?: 0f
                Glide.with(context)
                    .load(data.picturePath)
                    .into(ivPoster)
                itemView.setOnClickListener { view -> itemAdapterCallback.onClick(view, data) }
            }
        }
    }

    interface ItemAdapterCallback {
        fun onClick(v: View?, data:Data)
    }
}
```

Code for vertical recycleview fragment:

```
class HomeNewCraftFragment : Fragment(), HomeNewCraftAdapter.ItemAdapterCallback {

    private var adapter: HomeNewCraftAdapter? = null
    private var newcraftlist: java.util.ArrayList<Data>? = java.util.ArrayList()
    private var test: String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_new_craft, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        newcraftlist = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList("data")

        adapter = HomeNewCraftAdapter(newcraftlist!!, this)
        val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        rcListNewCraft.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rcListNewCraft.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?, data: Data) {
        val detail = Intent(activity, DetailActivity::class.java).putExtra("data", data)
        startActivity(detail)
    }
}
```

And I want to pass data here, on Detail Activity:

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

        intent.extras?.let {
            val navController = Navigation.findNavController(findViewById(R.id.detailHostFragment))
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable("data", it.get("data") as Parcelable?)
            navController.setGraph(navController.graph, bundle)
        }
    }

    fun toolbarPayment() {
        toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        toolbar.title = "Payment"
        toolbar.subtitle = "You deserve better meal"
        toolbar.navigationIcon = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_back)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
    }

    fun toolbarDetail() {
        toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

And fragment:

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    var data:Data?= null
    var bundle:Bundle?= null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as DetailActivity?)!!.toolbarDetail()

        arguments?.let {
            DetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).data.let {
                initView(it)
            }
        }

        btnOrderNow.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_fragmentDetail_to_fragmentPayment, bundle)
        }
    }

    private fun initView(data: Data?) {

        bundle = bundleOf("data" to data)

        Glide.with(requireContext())
            .load(data?.picturePath)
            .into(ivPoster)

        tvTitle.text = data?.name
        tvDescription.text = data?.description
        tvMaterials.text = data?.materials

//        tvTotal.formatPrice(data?.price.toString())
    }
}
```

and here is the navigation:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentDetail"
    android:id="@+id/nav_detail">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetail"
        android:name="com.project.icacraft.ui.detail.DetailFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentDetail_to_fragmentPayment"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentPayment" />

        <argument
            android:name="data"
            app:argType="com.project.icacraft.model.response.home.Data"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>
```

Here is xml for activiy_detail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.detail.DetailActivity">


    //Menambahkan toolbar dan detail fragment
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_detail"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include your `R.layout.activity_detail`

Comment: @ianhanniballake there it is, I already edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the Pass data to the start destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start):

> Note: when manually calling `setGraph()` with arguments, you must **not** use the `app:navGraph` attribute when creating the `NavHostFragment` in XML as that **will internally call `setGraph()` without any arguments**, resulting in your graph and start destination being created twice.

So you can fix your error by removing the `app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_detail"` line from your `activity_detail.xml` file.

You'll also need to change your `setGraph` call to use the same `R.navigation.nav_detail`:

```
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_detail, bundle)
```

Comment: I have this error when removing app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_detail"
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.icacraft.dev/com.project.icacraft.ui.detail.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you were calling `navController.setGraph(navController.graph, bundle)` - that never made sense. I've edited my answer to include that you need to use the `R.navigation.nav_detail` value in your `setGraph` to inflate `R.navigation.nav_detail`.

Comment: wow thank you verry much, you saved my day sir, I've been stuck on this problem for days, thank you it work to remove app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_detail" and change setGraph to "navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_detail, bundle)"